# visual studio 2015 default screen setting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i want to set the screen in visual studio 2015 but unable to fix the problem
[unable to set the default size of toolbox,errorlist ; properties is not showing on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFiUp.png)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correct, you want to reset the window layout to default size and location, then you should, in the menu click.

**Window -> Reset Window Layout.**